# Jquery better way to write a if condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I am working on a asp.net mvc code with jquery where I have to handle a if statement. I am confused if the way I have written is correct or not. Any suggestion on refractoring the below code?

```
@if (Model.HasRecords)
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#cancel").hide();
        });
    </script>
}
else
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#cancel").show();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could optimize it with a Razor ternary.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#cancel").@Html.Raw(Model.HasRecords ? "hide();" : "show();")
    });
</script>
```

Even better than bothering with this in JavaScript at all, you could just wrap your `#cancel` element in a statement that will only write it to the output if the model has any records. So up in your HTML, you could have something like this (assuming it's an input, but it could be any other type of HTML element):

```
@if (Model.HasRecords) {
    <input type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</input>
}
```

This would make a lot more sense.

Comment: why would you ever write code like this. You should just hide the html ahead of time rather than load it and rely on javascript to handle styling something that you could have easily done on the backend. Your javascript should be in an external file

Comment: I wouldn't write code like this, but I'm answering the OP's question. This would be the simplest way to accomplish the direct question that was asked.

Comment: it's definitely clever but it looks very hacky and poorly done. He wanted to know how he should refactor his code and I really think recommending something like this is wrong

Comment: An answer like my original would be something more suited for the Programming Golf Stack Exchange site. I've updated my answer with a different approach that doesn't go near JavaScript. My mindset when I got the question was more of a direct focus on what was asked than expanding and thinking of a completely different solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle conditional showing of something is to `$("#cancel").toggle();` As in, if something is hidden, toggle will show it. If it is shown, it will hide it. So if you ever needed to determine which function to use based on the state of a page, rather than determine whether it is hidden or shown and returning a function dynamically, you can just use `toggle` and let jquery do that work for you.

If these annotations are asp.net code, you should probably just handle the logic here and either not write the tag to your html at all, or add a `style="display:none"` for the #cancel html node. This is what show or hide is going to do for you under the covers in jquery so you might as well avoid conditionally adding in javascript and just add this style yourself. Looks a lot cleaner

Comment: You shouldn't use `toggle` as it wouldn't be going back and forth. It'd only ever be one or the other any time the page loads.

Comment: I know that's what toggle does. I just was letting him know that existed if thats what he was actually trying to do. Conditionally adding scripts is definitely not the way to go

Comment: If that's all the Javascript that is going to be on the page, then yeah. I would go with the inline adding of a class (instead of hard styling), or even not adding the button at all to the DOM with Razor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        @if (Model.HasRecords)
        {
            @:$("#cancel").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            @:$("#cancel").show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!